# Swift: UIAlertController in SwiftUI sheet bug

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uialertcontroller

I would like to include UIAlertController in my SwiftUI project because I have more customization options with UIAlertController than with swiftui alert. I've already partially done that with this code:

```
struct CustomAlertManager {
    
    static let shared = CustomAlertManager()
    
    private init() {}
    
    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Achtung", message: "Sie werden weiter geleitet", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in
            
        }
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        
        if let controller = UIApplication.shared.rootViewController {
            controller.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

My UIApplication extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
    var rootViewController: UIViewController? {
        let scene = self.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene

        return scene?.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }
}
```

**But now to my problem:**
This works pretty much fine but when I want to present an UIAlertController inside of a sheet the alert is not displayed (maybe its is unter the sheet). Note: No, the controller (UIApplication.shared.rootViewController) is not empty, so the .present(_:) method will be called .
Best regards!

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: This is a known thing it isn't a bug both the `sheet` and the `Alert` are being presented in the same spot in the `rootViewController`.  Don't use `rootViewController` if you need a `UIViewController` create one yourself and use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Comment: @loremipsum I thought so too. Thanks!

Comment: @burnsi no......

Comment: The rootViewController is a common thing people offer as a solution around here but it is just a shortcut/bandaid. Apple has changed the way to access it with every iteration of SwiftUI I don’t think they want people to use it as a rule.